# MediaStore Android

Tags: android, file, mediastore

I've just started learning about content providers and MediaStore, but there is one thing that I can't figure it out and the documentation on MediaStore is really poor. I understand that android uses a database to keep information about media files, for speed and power consumption reasons, and I saw it's fields, but I don't see how the mapping between database entries and and files is made. For example audio media has album, artists etc., but I couldn't find a field like path or something, also they don't provide a schema or something to help me understand the relations between all these elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#DATA) column is what you're looking for. That column has the file path to the particular file stored in it.

Comment: Ok...and let's say I want to add information about an audio file. Is it enough to insert data in `MediaStore.Audio.Media` or do I have to update albums, artists, all audio tables?

Comment: @Jelly Sorry, I don't know about that